# Add VLAN layer using PcapDotNet

Tags: c#, .net, packet

I have `Pcap file` that i try to add VLAN layer so i am using `PcapDotNet DLLs` like [this](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Sending%20Packets) example:

```
private Packet AddVlan(Packet packet)
{
    try
    {
        ILayer ethernet = packet.Ethernet.ExtractLayer();
        IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = (IpV4Layer)packet.Ethernet.VLanTaggedFrame.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
        ILayer payload = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Payload.ExtractLayer();
        DateTime packetTimestamp = packet.Timestamp;
        ipV4Layer.HeaderChecksum = null;
        VLanTaggedFrameLayer vLanTaggedFrameLayer =
            new VLanTaggedFrameLayer
            {
                PriorityCodePoint = ClassOfService.Background,
                CanonicalFormatIndicator = false,
                VLanIdentifier = 50,
                EtherType = EthernetType.IpV4,
            };

        return PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, vLanTaggedFrameLayer, ipV4Layer, payload);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My problem  is that the `Packet` looks that several layer is missing:

[image]

Any idea how solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused because the EthernetLayer you extract has IPv4 as the EtherType. You should change it to None if you want it to be auto calculated when you build the packet.

```
EthernetLayer ethernet = (EthernetLayer)packet.Ethernet.ExtractLayer();
ethernet.EtherType = EthernetType.None;
```